# Making div 100% height of browser window

Tags: css

I have two columns for my website and right now the background color ends at the last piece of content in the left column (which is for navigation).

I've tried height:100%, min-height:100%; etc. Doesn't seem to work. here's the css.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    background: #fbf6f0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:220px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #007cb8;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: set the body and html to a height of 100% as well...

Comment: possible duplicate of [For div to extend full height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535983/for-div-to-extend-full-height)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 8):

Use viewport height - vh.

```
.container {
height: 100vh;
}
```

**Update**

Please note, there are potential issues with using VH on Safari iOS. See this thread for more information: [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent)

Answer (score 5):

Set the body height too

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
}

div {
  height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `div` doesn't fill the entire window by default if because it's parent, the `<body>` tag probably, only stretches as heigh as it needs to. Add this at the top of your stylesheet (I like to order styles in a similar order to that of the tags in the markup):

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

*edit: grammar*

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

This css code is for your solution.