# HTML CSS automatic adjust full vertical length (height)

Tags: html, css

I want my div-blocks to automatically scale their height to full length of the screen. It should be screen resolution independent. How can I achieve that?

[Here is an img of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q42gl.png)

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Is the div's 'height' set to 100%?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For div to extend full height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535983/for-div-to-extend-full-height)

Comment: You can post a link to a jsbin, codepen or your actual code here rather than an image

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'm a bloody greenhorn as well in HTML/CSS as on steckoverflow. Thanks for the fast help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```