# Set 100% Height and Width for asp:content

Tags: asp.net

I have a Page Report.aspx with the following content:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <a:ShowPdf ID="ShowPdf1" Name="ShowPdf" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" FilePath="84ca0965220b47b592f9a0fc8aeb535c.pdf"
                 Height="100%" 
                 Width="100%" />
</asp:Content>
```

The Problem ist, that the Control ShowPDF is not showing with the full Height.

[image]

How can I set 100% Height for the Control?

Comment: A Content Control does not show up in html. You need to wrap it with a div and use CSS to set it's width and height.

Comment: @VDWWD - Can you give me a sample how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535983/for-div-to-extend-full-height