# How to put a div and nested divs with min height of all body

Tags: html, css

I have my body with border:5px solid blue, and I want to put my green div, as well as yellow div and orange div with min-height of 100% of the body.
I want my body Tag (and also my orange div and yellow div) to be at least 100% of the screen and it should grow if the content is added.

**My code:**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.top-menu {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 96.5%;
  left: 3.5%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.left-menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3.5%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="border:5px solid blue">
  <div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">

  </div>

  <div class="wrapper" style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">

      <!-- <app-side-menu></app-side-menu> -->

    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
      < O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um
        espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens
        com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos? É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando
        analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores
        de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente,
        por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor). De onde é que ele vem? Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000
        anos. Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura clássica, descobriu
        a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira
        linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32. O pedaço mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do
        "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham. Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica
        e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto
        para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o
        Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos? É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição
        mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por
        omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor). </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For div to extend full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535983/for-div-to-extend-full-height)

Comment: I already tried what is suggested in that question (define body height min 100% and wraper height 100%) as you can see in the code, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I've used Flexbox to achieve this with [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top-menu {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.main-content {
    width: 96.5%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-menu {
    width: 3.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper" style="border:5px solid green">

        <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">

            <!-- <app-side-menu></app-side-menu> -->

        </div>

        <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
            O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem
            Ipsum
            tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os
            caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o
            salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com
            a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com
            os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos?
            É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a
            sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao
            contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui" , tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de
            publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado
            por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias
            versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do
            humor). De onde é que ele vem? Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto
            aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos.
            Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras
            em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na
            literatura clássica, descobriu a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33
            do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é
            um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem
            Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32. O pedaço mais habitual do
            Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33
            do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados
            pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham. Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o
            Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem
            vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres
            de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para
            a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a
            disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os
            programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos? É
            um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua
            mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao
            contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui" , tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de
            publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado
            por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias
            versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do
            humor).
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've also set the box model to `border-box` so that the elements specified width and height aren't affected by padding or borders. Find out more about `box-sizing` [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Find out more about the CSS Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.main-content {
  height:100%;
}
.main-content div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.left-menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="border:5px solid blue;margin:0;">
  <div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">

  </div>

  <div class="wrapper" style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">

      <!-- <app-side-menu></app-side-menu> -->

    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
      <div> que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um
        espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens
        com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos? É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando
        analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores
        de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente,
        por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor). De onde é que ele vem? Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000
        anos. Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura clássica, descobriu
        a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira
        linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32. O pedaço mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do
        "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham. Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica
        e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto
        para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o
        Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum. Porque é que o usamos? É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição
        mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por
        omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor). </div>
    </div>
</body>
```